# How to get a dynamic number (n) of inputs from a string, where n is the first word?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a string which looks like the following.

```
"""
1: a
2: a, b
3: a, b, c
"""
```

I would like to use pyparsing to define a grammar which is dynamic and picks up the correct number of inputs after reading the number in the beginning of each line. If the number of inputs are not the same, it should give an error. I did look into some documentation, but I only found `Forward`, and I am not sure if I can use it for this sort of an application. How do I define grammar for this sort of an input using pyparsing?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, just edited it. I just wanted to know how to define grammar for such an input string?

Comment: You will need to install pyparsing and then write some code. When you've done that, and if you're still having trouble, create a new question that includes your effort

Comment: Pyparsing includes a helper method `counted_array` for this very type of application, but without the punctuation. You are correct, it uses a Forward for the varying-length portion, which gets initialized from a parse action attached to the leading numeric value.  You can find the code for `counted_array` here (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/2a1a8e8f4beee7fd120c3fdc1a48725b77e263c2/pyparsing/helpers.py#L20), and make some progress using that, or code of your own that follows that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (although pyparsing is not used):

```py
def parse(s):
    front, back = s.split(': ')
    n = int(front)
    l = back.split(', ')
    if n != len(l):
        raise ValueError(
            'number of strings is incorrect: {} != len({})'.format(n, l)
        )
    return n, l

lines = [
    '1: a',
    '2: a, b, c',
    '3: a, b, c',
]

for line in lines:
    n, l = parse(line)
    # maybe do something with n and l
```

When the given integer does not match the number of strings, an exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/to/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    n, l = parse(line)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/some/path/to/test.py", line 6, in parse
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: number of strings is incorrect: 2 != len(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```